# create array from range values VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

i'm trying to do a macro where i will need an array of values.
this array is created from a range which will be variable in size.
i've tried the below but keep having an error:

```
Sub chase()


Dim rng As Range
Dim myarray() As Variant

last = Range("r1").End(xlDown).Address
MsgBox last

myarray = Range("r1:" & last).Value
For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
        msg = msg & myarray(i) & vbNewLine
    Next i
MsgBox "the values of my dynamic array are: " & vbNewLine & msg


End Sub
```

any idea how to process?

thanks

Comment: A style note - I'm a BIG fan of picking the column, and going UP from the bottom of the column, as opposed to starting at the top and going DOWN - this will let you find the bottom, even if there's a gap in the middle of your data.

Answer (score 3):

Use the last row number in the range assignment.

```
dim last as long

last = Range("r1").End(xlDown).row
myarray = Range("r1:r" & last).Value
```

You're creating a 2-D array. Although some of the functions default to the first rank, it is better to treat a 2-D array as a 2-D array.

```
For i = LBound(myarray, 1) To UBound(myarray, 1)
        msg = msg & myarray(i, 1) & vbNewLine
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

See below:

```
Sub chase()

  Dim i As Integer, msg As String
  Dim last As Variant
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim myarray As Variant

  last = Sheet1.Range("r1").End(xlDown).Address
  MsgBox last

  myarray = Sheet1.Range("r1:" & last).Value
  For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
    msg = msg & myarray(i, 1) & vbNewLine
  Next i

  MsgBox "the values of my dynamic array are: " & vbNewLine & msg

End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure you prefix your range with the sheet that is referring to avoid unexpected results.

Comment: your array is two dimensional (x,y) so you need to be indexing the second dimension too.